# jquery on click go to url but no scroll to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this simple function to move a slideshow that have a hashNavigation.

All the slide have a data-hash the make a new link (I use swiper js library -> [link](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#hash-navigation))

```
<div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="red">
  <img src="/img.jpg">
</div>
<div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="blue">
   <img src="/img.jpg">
</div>
```

I have this input that on click move the slide.

```
<input class='red' type='radio' name='product_id' id='red' value='{$p->id}'>
 <label class='red' for='red'></label>
</input>
<input class='blue' type='radio' name='product_id' id='blue' value='{$p->id}'>
 <label class='blue' for='blue'></label>
</input>
```

and

```
$(".red").click(function(e){
    window.location = "link/#red"; //this is a inside link page
});
$(".blue").click(function(e){
    window.location = "link/#blue"; //this is a inside link page
});
```

So all work well But at the click also the page scroll to the element. How I can change url without have the scroll? just let the windows in the same position.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide us with more code or a code snippet with working demo

Comment: @MateuszJuruś absolutely true.
I think you can just remove the #red and then you will be redirected without scrolling to the element

Comment: yes sure now update the request.

Comment: Ok @lightstalker89 the question is update. Can you help me?

Comment: ok @MateuszJuruś the question is update. Can you help me?

Comment: guys, I will need this account you can take negative votes, please?

Comment: "But at the click also the page scroll to the element" yes that's what putting an element ID into a URL does, almost since day 1 of the web. It's just how browsers work. From reading that documentation link you provided (which also scrolls to an element ID which is included in the URL, notice!) it also seems that is the intention of the hash-navigation feature you're using - it's meant to display the image immediately when the page loads. It's not clear why you'd want to not have that? You want the user to click an image but then the page loads and doesn't scroll to show it? Confusing IMO

Comment: yes @ADyson, and thank you. More or less is the intention. I need the ID in the input for let work the label. But the input is under the images. So when I click on the input the slide move correctly and the page scroll also to the id in the input but is to much down on the page. So I need to let work the function for move the slide but without have the scroll to the ID in the input. You think is possible?

Comment: Not by this method I don't think so, I don't know of a way to override the built-in browser functionality which scrolls to an element ID if specified in the URL. Perhaps you can google if there is a way

Comment: OK thank you @ADyson. I will think something.

Comment: @ADyson other way for let work the label with the input?

Comment: Wait a minute...you're using the same ID for the input as the ID of your image...obviously they're going to clash. Yes you need an ID for your label to work correctly, but I don't see why you need the same ID as used in your data-hash? No wonder the page is confused. I only just noticed this. Swiper wants to use that #red in your URL to find the correct image, but you override that by using the same ID for your input.

Comment: @ADyson eheh you read my mind. I just have add to the data-hash this `data-hash="img_<?= $p->color_choose->title ?>"` and now I have a new data url! and change the jQuery. (the $p->color_choose->title are the api of PW) thank you for all! speck with you help me!

Comment: That's great. I wrote it as the proper answer in case you wish to accept it fully, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same ID for the input as the ID of your image...obviously they're going to clash.

Yes you need an ID for your label to work correctly, but I don't see why you need the same ID as used in your data-hash? No wonder the page is confused.

Swiper wants to use the `#red` ID in your URL to find the correct image, but you override that by using the same ID for your input, so it scrolls there instead.

You simply need to use a different ID for one or the other.